# Обработка исключения Format Exception

Tags: c#, winforms

Как корректно обработать исключение Format Exception на проверку введенных значений в TextBox?

Comment: `try { //do } catch (FormatException ex) {Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());}`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев можно вообще обойтись без исключения и его обработки. Существуют статические методы `TryParse()`, которые в случае неуспеха возвращают `false`. Например, проверка, что в поле ввели число, может выглядеть так:

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
{
    // работаем с value
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Введите число");
}
```